# Generate flowchart diagram from existing workflow rules

Tags: workflow

Are there any tools/apps available that can take existing workflow rules and generate flowchart diagrams for documenting processes?

We have many complex (read as: should probably be apex) workflows that were never documented. I am looking for a tool that will at least take those workflow and create a draft diagram to work off of, or a output file that could be imported into Visio or other tools to generate a diagram.

Comment: I dont think that there is any such tool. You will have to do that manually,

Comment: Sadly true, there are ones that generate the database schema but nothing like that for workflow rules.

Answer (score 0):

Currently there is no such application. It is definitely a good idea though. I am not sure if this is something you are willing to put a lot of time into, but if you want this to work you will need to do it manually.

Please mark this as the Best Answer to close this question.

Thanks,